# How to count and select records with count = 1 across multiple columns

Tags: sql

Hi and thanks in advance.

Trying to simplify two SQL statements without much success.

1. Count unique records in a table (by unique, I mean the whole record is found only once in the table)
2. Select unique records in a table (by unique, I mean the whole record is found only once in the table)

Since the table has 30 columns, is there some way to simply specify ALL columns in the table rather than having to include all individually in the SQL?

I got this working where you spell out every column name (where 'col n name' refers to the last column) but it is not ideal since there are just so many columns …

```
SELECT col 1 name, col 2 name, col 3 name, …, col n name FROM table name 
GROUP BY col 1 name, col 2 name, col 3 name, …, col n name
Having Count(*)=1
```

Thanks
deutz

Comment: In most databases, you have to specify all the columns.  You can use the schema metadata to get the names if you don't want to type them.

Comment: For #2, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT`, which at least removes the need for a `GROUP BY` clause which repeats the full list of column names a second time.

Comment: Thanks Gordon and Tim.   Tim, I think DISTINCT will get one of each record regardless of how many times it appears in the table.  I require just the records that appear only once in the table. Unfortunately, I don't think you can specify COUNT = 1 in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps your product has some fancy functionality that can be used here.)

Answer (score 0):

```
create view tab_view1 as select DISTINCT * from tab; 
select COUNT(*) from tab_view1; -- first desired result
select * from tab_view1; -- second desired result
```

First occurence is unique, second is not.

If you want to exclude any record that has duplicate:

```
create view tab_view2 as select tab.*, COUNT(*) AS occurs
from tab group by tab.*
having COUNT(*) = 1; 
select COUNT(*) from tab_view2; -- first desired result
select * from tab_view2; -- second desired result
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene,  I'll check this out when I get a moment.

Comment: That GROUP BY is product specific and not valid ANSI SQL.

Comment: You can always list all table columns easily

Comment: Looks like there is no easy way to refer to all columns in a table in this instance.  In any case, thanks for your suggestions.  deutz